# what is the meaning of this error when i run my project

Tags: c#

i got this error in c#

```
'Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
uses 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' which has a higher version
than referenced assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.3.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
```

what is the meaning of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a [AssemblyName mismatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/416tef0c%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The version of the Assembly you are refreencing is wrong, try re add the reference to the assembly by removing and readding

Answer (score 0):

One of your referenced assembly use `MySql.Data` version `6.3.5.0` and you also use `MySql.Data` but the version `6.2.3.0`. ([Compiler Error CS1705](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/416tef0c.aspx))

Change the referenced assembly version of MySql.Data to 6.3.5.0